# Move overlay left to right with specific overlay starting position

Tags: ffmpeg

The command below moves image left to right, starting from outside the frame on the left side, with opacity on the image.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i bar.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork];[0:v][zork]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,100),-w+(t)*100,100)':y=0" output.mp4
```

What I need, is to have the image being full-screen in the beginning of the video, and then slowly moving towards the right side, never completely exiting the frame up right up until the point where the video finishes(image still fullscreen as video ends).

So the tempo has to vary based on the video length, for the image not to exit the frame at neither the start or finishing point.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i bar.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork];[0:v][zork]overlay=x=-w+((W+w)/N)*t" output.mp4
```

- Where `N` is the duration of `test.mp4`. So if `test.mp4` is 30 seconds long change `N` to `30`.
- You can [get duration with `ffprobe`](https://superuser.com/a/945604/).
- See [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).